# How can I delete an object with navigation property with entity framework 5 code first?

Tags: code-first, entity-framework-5, delete-row

I'm using EF 5 code first and I have 2 related entities ApplicationPermission and Application:

```
public class ApplicationPermission
{
   public virtual Application Application { get; set; }

   public int Id { get; set; }
} 

public class Application 
{
   public string Name { get; set; }

   public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

with the following mapping for ApplicationPermission:

```
HasKey(x => x.Id);
HasRequired(x => x.Application).WithMany().Map(m => m.MapKey("ApplicationId")).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

and for Application:

```
HasKey(x => x.Id);
```

I use the code below for deleting ApplicationPermission:

```
ApplicationPermission entity = new ApplicationPermission { Id = id };
DbContext.Set<ApplicationPermission>().Attach(entity);
DbContext.Set<ApplicationPermission>().Remove(entity);
DbContext.SaveChanges();
```

But I got an error on SaveChanges method:

> Entities in 'CodeFirstContainer.ApplicationPermissions' participate in
>   the 'ApplicationPermission_Application' relationship. 0 related
>   'ApplicationPermission_Application_Target' were found. 1
>   'ApplicationPermission_Application_Target' is expected.

**How can I delete ApplicationPermission without loading Application to the dbcontext?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it's not possible to delete an entity without having set required navigation properties when you use *independent associations*. You must load the `Application` from the database or - at least - know the foreign key value and attach an `Application` entity with that value, like so:

```cs
ApplicationPermission entity = new ApplicationPermission { Id = 1 };
entity.Application = new Application { Id = 5 };
DbContext.Set<ApplicationPermission>().Attach(entity); //attaches Application too
DbContext.Set<ApplicationPermission>().Remove(entity);
DbContext.SaveChanges();
```

The SQL command generated when you call `SaveChanges` is then:

```sql
exec sp_executesql N'delete [dbo].[ApplicationPermissions]
where (([Id] = @0) and ([ApplicationId] = @1))',N'@0 int,@1 int',@0=1,@1=5
```

As you can see the query for the `delete` does not only ask for the `Id` of the `ApplicationPermission` to delete but also (`and`) the foreign key value for `ApplicationId`. In order to succeed you must know and set this FK value by setting the related entity with the same primary key.

The problem does not occur when using *foreign key associations*:

```cs
public class ApplicationPermission
{
    public virtual Application Application { get; set; }
    public int ApplicationId { get; set; }

    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationPermission>()
    .HasRequired(x => x.Application)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.ApplicationId)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

You can then use your original code without setting the FK property `ApplicationId` to a correct value (will default to `0` then) and without setting the navigation property and deleting the entity will work. The SQL command doesn't care about the FK and just queries for the `Id` of the `ApplicationPermission` to delete:

```sql
exec sp_executesql N'delete [dbo].[ApplicationPermissions]
where ([Id] = @0)',N'@0 int',@0=1
```

I have no idea why the SQL commands are different between the two types of associations.